# Using Python dictionary as parameter and variable in Python Toolbox tool of ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, parameters, python-toolbox, list, dictionary

I'm building a feature class merging and comparing toolbox in arcpy, ArcGIS 10.7.
I have a working command line utility with fixed featureclass values, and now I'm building this toolbox, I just copy the relevant sections:

```
        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(  
        displayName="My filter list:",  
        name="fc_dict",  
        datatype="GPString",  
        parameterType="Required",  
        direction="Input",
        multiValue = True)
    params = [param0, param1, param2]
    return params
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    fdict = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
    exportList = []
    for key in fdict:
        exportList.append(key)            
    parameters[2].filter.list = exportList
    return
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

    import os
    exportList = parameters[2].valueAsText
    for search in exportList.split(";"):

        arcpy.AddMessage("Exporting " + search)
```

With this I can populate my GPString with the keys and use them, what's nice. But I have to use my values also as variable. But I don't understand the accessing approach.

Comment: welcome to GIS SE. I think your question is more so about general python rather than GIS. If I get your question right, you will find your solution here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp --> fdict['key1'] will return value1

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I think that a code snippet for a Python Toolbox tool needs to be a full `test.pyt` that shows only the tool class(es) needed to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: dru87- Thank you for your welcome, and the hint of information. I know how to access normally a value, but i don't know what to do in this situation. i list the optionable keys in the GPsring parameter. And i just pass over keys in the exportList variable.  I don't want to show my values for the user, but i dont know how to reach a selected key's pairs.

Comment: PolyGeo- Thank you for the guidance. I try my best.

Comment: I doubt you can use a real dictionary as a parameter, but a text string in JSON or a file path to a JSON string would work. The list you are trying to use only keeps the keys of the key/value pairs, so this can't work. The great part about JSON use is the `json` Python module, which supports `dumps()` and `loads()` methods.